# How to create a tiny no titlebar notification window using QML and PyQt5

Tags: python, qt, notifications, qml, pyqt5

How can we create a tiny notification window using QML without a title bar? For example, look at the picture. This notification seems like created by GTK.

[image: This Image.]

can we create on like this using PyQt5 and QML

Comment: Are you looking for `Notification` perhaps? https://doc.qt.io/QtApplicationManager/qml-qtapplicationmanager-notification.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QML is very flexible language, you can create almost whatever you want. In your case I would use some system tool, since it't cross platform and works as expected. But you always can create some custom window, for example:

```js
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5
import Qt.labs.platform 1.1

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 400
    height: 100

    RowLayout {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        Button {
            text: "systray message"
            onClicked: {
                systray.showMessage("title", "message", SystemTrayIcon.Warning, 2000)
            }
        }
        Button {
            text: "custom message"
            onClicked: {
                popup.show();
            }
        }
    }

    SystemTrayIcon {
        id: systray
          visible: true
          icon.source: "qrc:/ok.png"
          icon.mask: false
    }

    Window {
        id: popup
        flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint
        x: Screen.width - 350
        y: Screen.height - 150
        width: 300
        height: 30
        Rectangle {
            anchors.fill: parent
            color: "black"
            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: "Some custom message"
                color: "white"
            }
        }
        Timer {
            id: timer
            interval: 2000;
            running: false;
            repeat: false
            onTriggered: popup.close()
        }
        onVisibleChanged: {
            if(visible)
                timer.running = true;
        }
    }
}
```